# How to Draw Lines if a Condition is Satisfied and Save All Lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I am using Node.Js and attempting to draw lines around portions of an image whenever a condition proves true. I'm essentially trying to outline objects in an image response from an API. I have a response coming in from an API and whenever that response contains "WORD", I would like to draw two lines that encase a portion of an image. At the end, I would like to save all the lines that were drawn and export the image, now with the lines drawn on it.

I have managed to get the response from the API, loop through the objects in the response, and check to see if the objects match a filtering condition. I have then managed to draw one set of lines, but I cannot determine how to draw the lines everytime the condition is satifised and save all the resulting drawings. The resulting image only has a single group of lines drawn on it. I am using the Images package as well as Canvas.

```
// get image
var ImageDATA = await getImage()

// Get the height, width of the image
const dimensions = sizeOf(ImageDATA.Body)
const width = dimensions.width
const height = dimensions.height
console.log(ImageDATA.Body)
console.log(width, height)

try{
  // Call API and log response
  const res = await client.detectDocumentText(params).promise();
  // set the response as an image and get width and height
  var image = images(ImageDATA.Body).size(width, height)
  //console.log(res)
  res.Blocks.forEach(block => {
    if (block.BlockType.indexOf('WORD') > -1)
    {
      //console.log("Word Geometry Found.");
      console.log("FOUND POLYGONS")
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
      console.log(block.Geometry.Polygon[0].X)
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(width * block.Geometry.Polygon[3].X, height * block.Geometry.Polygon[3].Y);
      ctx.moveTo(width * block.Geometry.Polygon[1].X, height * block.Geometry.Polygon[1].Y);
      ctx.lineTo(width * block.Geometry.Polygon[2].X, height * block.Geometry.Polygon[2].Y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    console.log("-----")
  }) 

  // render image
  // convert canvas to buffer
  var buffer = canvas.toBuffer("image/png");
  // draw the buffer onto the image
  image.draw(images(buffer), 10, 10)
  // save image
  image.save("output.jpg");
  
} catch (err){
console.error(err);}
```

Here's a sample of the Polygon array:

```
[
  { X: 0.9775164723396301, Y: 0.985478401184082 },
  { X: 0.9951508641242981, Y: 0.985478401184082 },
  { X: 0.9951508641242981, Y: 0.9966437816619873 },
  { X: 0.9775164723396301, Y: 0.9966437816619873 }
]
```

It defines the boundary starting from the top-left and moving clockwise.

If anyone knows how to achieve this, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you share the content of one of the `block.Geometry.Polygon` array, are the vertices returned by the API ordered clockwise or counter clockwise or not ordered at all ... one last thing most object recognition  APIs have some king of utility methods for these kind of operations (drawing the outline) check the doc see if there are any

Comment: I didn't see a convenient method of drawing the bounding box, but I've updated my question with the Polygon array and clockwise format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    block.Geometry.Polygon.forEach(({X, Y}) =>
      ctx.lineTo(width * X, height * Y)
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const boudingBoxes = [
  {
    label: "Pen",
    polygon: [
      {x: 0.60, y: 0.64},
      {x: 0.83, y: 0.66},
      {x: 0.82, y: 0.70},
      {x: 0.60, y: 0.70},
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Camera",
    polygon: [
      {x: 0.72, y: 0.20},
      {x: 0.93, y: 0.25},
      {x: 0.88, y: 0.43},
      {x: 0.71, y: 0.39},
    ]
  },
]


init();

async function init() {
  const image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = "";
  await new Promise(res => {
    image.onload = res;
    image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/180/600/400";
  });
  
  const [width, height] = [image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight];
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  // Draw the image
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  
  // Start Drawing the bounding boxes
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  boudingBoxes.forEach(bBox => {
  
    // label
    ctx.font = "13px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText(bBox.label, width * bBox.polygon[0].x, height * bBox.polygon[0].y - 6);

    // Bounding box
    ctx.beginPath();
    bBox.polygon.forEach(({x, y}) =>
      ctx.lineTo(width * x, height * y)
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);  
}

// TMP 
const p = document.querySelector("p");
window.onmousemove = (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX / 600;
  const y = e.clientY / 400;
  p.innerHTML = `x: ${x} <br/> y: ${y}`;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

p {position: absolute }
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: That was it! Apparently I needed to do lineTo for each and then close the path afterwards. Thanks so much, I really appreciate it!